# jQuery :not() selector does not work in .off() methode

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Why is the `:not()` or `:has()` selector in the `.off()` method not fully supported?

`$(document).off()` unbinds ALL events in the document.

`$(document).off('.MyNamspace')` unbinds ALL events created with the namespace `'MyNamspace'` e.g. `$(document).on('click.MyNamespace','a',function(){})`

but

`$(document).off(':not(.MyNamspace)')` returns an regular expression error

Is it possible to implement this later?

Problem in more detail:

Suppose I have an HTML base framework with e.g. a navigation bar and some events bound it with a defined qualifier. In this framwork is a container that holds variable content and dynamically loaded JavaScript and also bound events on elements in the dynamically loaded container.

If the content changes, I also want to remove the associated JavaScript parts and ALL events except my own (and other like bootstraps events) createt for the framework.

The dynamically loaded JavaScript is strictly loaded into an object like:

```
foo = new whatEverYouWant();
```

When the content of the container will replaced by other content, I set foo to undefined or null and all defined variables and methodes are gone.

But if a user assigned an event like:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  console.lg(e,'bla bla bla');
});
```

the event will be hold after removing the content.

Comment: Because those are element selector filters...not event or namespace filters

Comment: `$(document).not('.someClass').off('someEvent')`?

Comment: .not() works only with (classes) element selectors not with namespaces :O/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no magic way to filter namespaces.

You can however access all jQuery events assigned to an element using `$._data(element,'events')`.

The object returned uses eventName as keys , each key containing an array of objects that contain properties like `namespace` and `selector` among others.

Then you can iterate the various events and do something like:

```js
/**
 * @param {DomNode} element - Element to remove namespaced events from.
 * @param {array} keepNamespaces - Array of namespaces not to remove.
 */
function removeOtherNameSpaces(element, keepNamespaces) {
  var events = $._data(element, 'events'),
      $el = $(element);
  
  $.each(events , function(eventName, arr) {    
    $.each(arr, function(_, obj) {
      if (!obj) return;

      if (obj.namespace && $.inArray(obj.namespace, keepNamespaces) === -1) {
        console.log('Removed:: Event:',eventName,', namespace: ', obj.namespace)
        $el.off('.' + obj.namespace);
      }
    });
  });
}

// DEMO
$(document).on('click.click-1', 'p', function() {
  console.log('Namespace: click-1 triggered')
}).on('click.click-2', 'p', function() {
  console.log('Namespace: click-2 triggered')
}).on('mouseenter.mouse-1', 'p', function() {
  console.log('Namespace: mouse-1 triggered')
})

$('button').click(function() {
  var keepNamespaces = ['click-1'];
  removeOtherNameSpaces(document, keepNamespaces)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Hover & Click me - before click button
</p>
<button>
  Remove namespace events
</button>
```

This could also be extended to only remove events from a specific delegated target selector also

Comment: perfect - I think it's looks like exactly what I needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, not what I was looking for. This script can only delete events having explicitly assigned namespaces :O(

Comment: Can be adjusted to remove other events also. Your question implied using namespaces

Comment: I think this is only possible if it is legitimate to delete the events from this list instead of deleting them using the provided method.

Comment: What list? Create a demo in jsfiddle or other sandbox site that shows what you would like to accomplish

Comment: The event list. E.g. all 'click' events are stored in an array accessible via $._data(document,'events').click - if I want to delete a click event stored in index 4 I can write: delete $._data(document,'events').click[4];

Comment: Only if you know what index it is

Comment: I currently don't find a way to add codesnip into a comment. So I describe my attempt in words. Based on your code snipset I'll expand the $.each() loop arround the index, go through the events an check the obj.namespace on e.g. !startsWith('keepNamspaces') and if it is true, I delete the object with the corresponding index from the objectlist. I know that the ._data() methode is undocumented, but at the Moment it is the only way to get the event data.

Comment: Don't `delete` use `off()` and jQuery will remove it. Put code into a sandbox site like jsfiddle.net, plunker, codepen etc

Comment: I can't use `.off()` on delegated, non qualified events! If I remove a 'click' event  with `.off('click')` I also remove my own qualified events... That's why a ask for an `:not` or `:has`modifier curently not implemented in jQuery

Comment: But should be able to also use the event handler argument also so yours don't get removed ... `off ('click', handler)`

Comment: Look at this demo https://jsfiddle.net/8yjuduqn/ . Removes events if they don't have your namespace (or any name space). Could modify it to only remove specific event types like `click` that aren't yours if needed

Comment: Thank you for your support! I did not know about obj.handler - no it works for me.

Answer (score -2):

As you can see on the [JQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off/)  you cant use selectors on events parameter

> .off( events [, selector ] [, handler ] )
>
> **events Type:**
>   String One or more space-separated event types and
>   optional namespaces, or just namespaces, such as "click",
>   "keydown.myPlugin", or ".myPlugin".

You do

`.off([ selector ])`

So you have to do

`$(document).off('events ','[selector]')`

Comment: Namespaces are used for events. Has nothing to do with element selectors

Comment: Lol read the damn API before you downvote you cant use selector on events you have to write them space seperated

Comment: Read the damn question before answering. OP appears to want to remove all event handlers *except* those in a given namespace.

Comment: No it appears to want to use JQuery :not() selector into the events parameter and thats NOT POSSIBLUR